# Updating an array with a For loop in ARMv8

Tags: assembly, arm64, armv8

I have an assignment to convert C code into ARMv8 assembly code. The C code snippet I was given is as follows:

```
int m=5;
int k;
int a[5];
for(int k=0; k<5;k++){
   m=m+k;
   a[k]=k;
}
printf("m=%d\n",m);
printf("k=%d\n",k);
```

So basically I have to run a for loop to populate an array with the corresponding index value, as well as increase the value of M by the index value. This is what I tried:

```
.text
.global main

main:
   adr x1, array
   mov x2, array_length
   mov x3, #0
   mov x4, xzr
   adr x5, m

loop:
   cmp x3, x2
   bge done
   add x4, x1, x3, lsl #3
   str x3, [x4]
   add x5, x5, x3
   add x3, x3, #1
   b loop

done:
   mov x1, x5
   adr x0, str1
   bl printf

   mov x1, x4
   adr x0, str2
   printf

exit:
   mov x8, #93
   svc 0

.data
.set array_length, 5
m: .word 5
str1: .asciz "m=%d\n"
str2: .asciz "k=%d\n"
array: .dword 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

It compiles and executes fine, but the values it gives me are very wrong (in the thousands when they should be single or double digits). I based my code on a similar example given by the professor and those were the values she used so I'm not sure how it's coming out so wrong.

Comment: I don't see any load or store of `m` anywhere?  `adr x5, m` loads `x5` with the address of `m` (probably your number in the thousands) rather than the value stored there in memory (5).

Comment: And in the second printf, your loop index `k` was in `x3`, not `x4`.  But the first `printf` is potentially going to trash `x0-x15` so you'd better save it somewhere else, such as `x19-x28`.  (If you were going to return from `main` you'd need to preserve those registers, but since you will exit via syscall it doesn't matter.)

Comment: I changed "adr x5, m" to "ldr x5, m" and now the result for that part is m=15, which I think is correct, but k is still wrong even after changing the printf to x3 from x4.

Comment: Yes, like I said in my previous comment, your first `printf` call overwrites all of those registers.

Comment: Ok changing one of them to X20 worked, thank you!!!